# cx_Freeze Unicode Decode Error

Tags: python, tkinter, cx-freeze

I am trying to convert an application I have made into an executable file using the script below

```
import cx_Freeze
import sys

base = None

if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = 'Win32GUI'

executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable('MainWindow.py', base=base, icon='Iconn.ico')]

cx_Freeze.setup(
    name = 'Student Analysis',
    options = {'build_exe': {'packages':['tkinter', 'MyLibrary']}},
    version = '0.1',
    description = 'Student analysis program',
    executables = executables
)
```

However, when I run this through the cmd, I get an error saying

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 2862: invalid start byte
```

The most recent call was the very last line, where executables = executables.
I've tried looking around and all I've found is answers based for pygame.